# Which XML encoding for storing filenames?

Tags: xml, character-encoding, sh

I would like to store raw filenames in an XML document but the encoding doesn't allow it.

Here's how you can generate a `test.xml` with the shell:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF > test.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <music></music>
    <file><![CDATA[$(printf \\xf1.mp3)]]></file>
</root>
EOF
```

Now if I try to read it with any XML parser (for example python):

```py
import xml.dom.minidom
xml.dom.minidom.parse('test.xml')
```

I get encoding problems:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 4, column 19
```

Is there a way to make XML allow any byte (but `NUL`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an encoding issue `tmp.xml:4: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xF1 0x2E 0x6D 0x70     <file><![CDATA[�.mp3]]></file>` . So printf \xf1 creates a non utf8 character.

Converting the ISO-8859-1 filenames to UTF-8

```
cat <<EOF > tmp.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <music></music>
    <file><![CDATA[$(printf \\xf1.mp3 | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8)]]></file>
</root>
EOF
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <music></music>
    <file><![CDATA[ñ.mp3]]></file>
</root>
```

If source enconding is unknown a workaround could be to store base64 strings.

```
printf \\xf1.mp3 | base64
8S5tcDM=
```

Changing the encoding of the XML gives no error

```
cat <<EOF > tmp.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <music></music>
    <file><![CDATA[$(printf \\xf1.mp3)]]></file>
</root>
EOF
```

Testing with `xmllint`

```
xmllint tmp.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <music></music>
    <file><![CDATA[�.mp3]]></file>
</root>
```

A question mark is shown since it's a utf-8 console printing ISO-8859-1 text.

Comment: That makes sense, ISO-8859-1 is a 8-bit encoding so it's more suited for storing arbitrary filenames in it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused between two separate issues:

(a) Character repertoire. XML 1.0 can include any character in the set

```
#x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

If you want to hold data (typically binary data) that's outside that range (for example NUL, #x0), you need to find some way of representing the binary data as characters; the most common choice is Base64.

(b) Encoding. The list of allowed characters above is defined in terms of Unicode codepoints. But there are different ways of representing (encoding) these codepoints as binary octets. You need to ensure that the encoding that is actually used is properly declared: if the file says it's UTF-8, then it must actually be UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I can decide about the format of the template file (XML, JSON, etc...), but I don't have a hand on the engine that will replace the tokens in it with raw values; one of those tokens is for a filename, so any byte could potentially appear. I thought that `]]>` of CDATA was less likely to appear than `"` or `'` in a filename (no guarantee though); I'm trying to determine when the generated XML might brake.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't attempt to create XML "by hand" using string concatenation unless you're very careful about writing the logic needed to escape special characters. Much better to use an XML-aware library. But if you want to do it in shell-script then that's going to be a bit tricky.

Comment: @Fravadona: Note that if "any byte could potentially appear," no changing of the encoding or wrapping in CDATA can help.  As Michael explains in point (a), certain characters are not allowed *at all* in an XML document.  To pass content through XML that could contain any illegal characters, such content will have to be represented (sometimes *encoded* is used here, but such use clashes confusingly with the character encoding discussed in Michael's part (b)) in another manner such as Base64.